# Pass Elements into Named Slots - Nothing Rendered

Tags: lightning-web-components, slots

### Problem

Trying to build a reusable component that I can pass components (lightning-button(s) for example) into.

### Troubleshooting Attempted

- An unnamed single slot passes the "header" button in just fine.
- Passing different element types in child component (span vs. div)
- Use of querySelector to set a {variable} on the parent component.
- Read: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/create_components_best_composition and attempted to use an event to let the parent component know the child component has loaded.

### ParentComponent (.html)

```
<template>
     <slot name="header"></slot>
     <slot name="footer"></slot>
</template>
```

### ChildComponent (.html)

```
<template>
   <c-parent-component>
     <div slot="header">
          <lightning-button label="Header Button 1"></lightning-button>
          <lightning-button label="Header Button 2"></lightning-button>
     </div>
     <div slot="footer">
          <lightning-button label="Footer Button 1"></lightning-button>
          <lightning-button label="Footer Button 2"></lightning-button>
     </div>
   </c-parent-component>
</template>
```

Comment: [Here's your code](https://studio.webcomponents.dev/edit/z8ik4gvTul1XZHoPrNTx/src/app.html?p=stories). It works fine. Maybe there's something else you're doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our issue was we had a `<lightning-card>` component wrapping the child component that interfered with the slots (not shown in the original question). Went down a rabbit hole thinking named slots and unnamed slots worked different with elements vs. text content, which was NOT the case. They both take in elements the same way.

`<lightning-card>` natively has slots and use of slots in the card failed to pass it up.

The above code works as sdfcfox mentioned:

### ParentComponent (.html)

```
<template>
     <slot name="header"></slot>
     <slot name="footer"></slot>
</template>
```

### ChildComponent (.html)

```
<template>
   <c-parent-component>
     <div slot="header">
          <lightning-button label="Header Button 1"></lightning-button>
          <lightning-button label="Header Button 2"></lightning-button>
     </div>
     <div slot="footer">
          <lightning-button label="Footer Button 1"></lightning-button>
          <lightning-button label="Footer Button 2"></lightning-button>
     </div>
   </c-parent-component>
</template>
```